# iPhone - button in UITableViewCell does not change image

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uiimageview, uibutton, uiimage

I'm trying to do some cell creation using Xcode 4.2 storyboarding, and using Interface Builder to create a custom cell. I get the cell created fine, and I have a button within it, I am trying to have it when I press the button, the image changes, however it does not seem to work. This is what I have

```
- (IBAction)sendToFavorites:(id)sender {
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[[sender superview] superview];
    int row = [feedTableView indexPathForCell:cell].row;
    NSLog(@"\"%@\" is FAVORITED", [[_allEntries objectAtIndex:row] articleTitle]);
    if ([[_allEntries objectAtIndex:row] isFavorited]) {
        NSLog(@"Unfavorite");
        [[_allEntries objectAtIndex:row] setFavorite:NO];
        [[sender imageView] setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"StarEmpty"]];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Favorite");
        [[_allEntries objectAtIndex:row] setFavorite:YES];
        [[sender imageView] setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"StarFilled"]];
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: do you get the logs (unfavorite/favorite)?

Comment: Yes, all NSLogs print as they should.

Comment: Also, when switching images, it seems to do it for a split second, but sticks with the StarEmpty. Would I be because in IB I have the image set to StarEmpty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

```
    [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"StarEmpty"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Can't set it alone, have to set it with a state, whether it is Highlighted, Normal, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You could try and refresh the content of the table view. I.e., calling `reloadData` on your table view after setting the new image associated to the cell.

As far as I understand from you code, you are trying to modify the cell content directly. Instead, this should happen through the `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` mechanism that controls the redraw of a table. So, simply: modify your data source, and redraw the table.

Hope this helps.

Comment: that doesn't work, it seems to not even look like the UITableView is changed at all. I'm trying to avoid this anyways.